# Is there a way to unify methods involving only functional interfaces into one?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I have many classes, each implementing `GeneralInterface` and possibly additional functional interfaces:

```
interface GeneralInterface {}

class MyObjectTypeOne implements GeneralInterface { /*...*/}

class MyObjectTypeTwo implements GeneralInterface, InterOne { /*...*/}

class MyObjectTypeThr implements GeneralInterface, InterOne, InterTwo { /*...*/}
```

I have a list which holds these `MyObjectTypeXXX` instances

```
class ListHolder {

    public static List<GeneralInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();

    ListHolder() {

        list.add(new MyObjectTypeOne());
        list.add(new MyObjectTypeTwo());
        list.add(new MyObjectTypeTwo());
        // add any number of any of the types
    }
}
```

and 20-40 functional interfaces. Here are 2 examples:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface InterOne {

    boolean onInterOne();

    static void iterate() {

        for (GeneralInterface obj : ListHolder.list) {
            if (obj instanceof InterOne) {
                if (((InterOne) obj).onInterOne())
                    System.out.println("yes");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface InterTwo {

    boolean onInterOne(String string);

    static void iterate(String string) {

        for (GeneralInterface obj : ListHolder.list) {
            if (obj instanceof InterTwo) {
                if (((InterTwo) obj).onInterTwo(string))
                    System.out.println("yes");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At different places in the code I need to call different `iterate` methods:

```
InterTwo.iterate("S");
InterOne.iterate();
```

My problem is that I need to maintain the `iterate` method for all functional interfaces while they are effectively doing same: checking if the object implements that interface, (casting it) and calling its only abstract method with the given arguments.

Is there a way, via syntax or design, to maintain only 1 method that does this?  I know that with reflection there is a bad way of doing this (I am showing it just to show that I did my research, I don't want it):

```
static void iterate(Class<?> clazz, Object arg) {

    for (GeneralInterface obj : ListHolder.list) {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
            Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
            Method functional;
            for (Method m : methods) {
                if (m.getModifiers() == Modifier.ABSTRACT) {
                    functional = m;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ((boolean) functional.invoke(obj, arg)) // cast arg or do some other trick
                System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your reflection scenario, you'd only be able to use `Object` parameters so it isn't perfectly functionable, am I wrong? Or add a cast to the class of parameters used in the functional method.

Comment: @YassinHajaj About the reflection way, yes, there will either be a cast in the invocation or some other trick. It's not that important since it's a bad way to go anyway.

Comment: Could you explain what is your actual problem you are trying to solve using a bunch of interfaces ? It seems to be an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @kordirko It's http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/318164/what-is-a-good-design-to-couple-relate-methods-and-references where I try to go with the advice of Erik there.

Comment: Seems to me that this problem is only related with refactoring. Please  have loook at [SOLID](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/5-class-design-principles-solid-in-java/) principles and revise your code. Also please have a good read on [Java Design Patterns](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/) to really grasp these concepts and improve your architecture.

Comment: I've read the link to the questionyou provided, and also other related question-none of them have answer. It seems not to be only XY problem, but WXYZ problem. In all of these question you are asking about your subsequent attempted solutions XYZ, each one on the higher level of abstraction, rather than asking for your actual problem W, that is unclear. It seems You are get stuck on what you believe is the proper solution (X->Y->Z) to the problem W, and you are unable step back and explain the real problem W in full. I thing you need to reset, take a breath, and start again from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has a few points that need improvement, but I've focused only on giving you a response for your specific problem. I think that you need to pass that common method to an intermediate abstract class:

```
abstract class MyObjectTypeAbstract {
   abstract boolean onInter(String ... testString);
   abstract boolean onInter();
   void iterate(String string) {

       for (GeneralInterface obj : ListHolder.list) {
           if (obj instanceof InterTwo) {
               if (onInter(testString))
                   System.out.println("yes");
           }
       }
   }
   void iterate() {

       for (GeneralInterface obj : ListHolder.list) {
           if (obj instanceof InterTwo) {
               if (onInter())
                   System.out.println("yes");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

What this does is to make you implement the only thing that seems to be different for every **FunctionalInterface** you provided. That is the **onInter** method. That seems to be different. So I made this abstract. The rest is shared. I've also taken out the **static** from the iterate methods so that they can access the different implementations of the onInter method. Hopefully you don't need this one to be static. So the solution I'm presenting is to make your classes *extend* this *abstract* class and *implement* the interfaces as now.

Comment: My objects are already extending a class, but maybe I can integrate this behavior into it.

Comment: I've re-read this and you're not taking into account that there can be several interfaces with the same abstract method argument. This will not allow the overloading you want. Besides, lumping all of the methods into the same class is what I'm trying to avoid, See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/318164/what-is-a-good-design-to-couple-relate-methods-and-references.

Comment: But you do want to avoid repeated code right? At least that's what I though you were trying to do. If you really want to make a good solution I think you need to get rid of the static iterate() you now have and you really need to change the way you have this architecture built. There just isn't any good solution to keep your current code. If you want a perfect solution that follow  [SOLID](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/5-class-design-principles-solid-in-java/) principles, then you need to give up on what you have,reset and start again. My "solution" is just an idea to work around it.